# Choosing edge in Kruskal's algorithm to form MST

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[image]

In the given picture, I was trying to form an Minimum Spanning Tree and I wonder if we can select the edge (FB) because it crosses an another edge (AG).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intersection in the picture means nothing in terms of graph.

Comment: Yes, you can choose it. Keep in mind that the picture of a graph is not the graph. It's just a representation of it. This graph was drawn in one particular way out of infinite possibilities. If the vertex A is moved to the right so that it's x-coordinate is between F and G, then there's no crossing

Answer (score 1):

Crossing in a graph the way you probably mean it depends on the particular embedding of the graph on the plane, so it does not mean much for the actual graph when you are trying to find a minimum spanning tree. (A graph can have infinitely many ways of embedding it on a plane)

The way Kruskal's algorithm works is that at every step you choose an edge $uv$ such that $u$ and $v$ are in different components, and $uv$ is the *lightest* edge satisfying this property.